# Array values based calculation

Tags: php-7

**Input:**  Given the array of dynamic values .

For EX:

i=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

**Expected Output:** (array of i)/n

**For EX:(array of i/3)**

1)1,2,3

2)3,4,5

3)6,7,8

How to do this

Thanks

Comment: You would be better of asking this at [so] because it is about generic PHP and not Magento specific

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belong to stack overflow not mse

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solution:

```
$i = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$n = 3;

print_r(array_chunk($i,$n)); //Without same key position

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )

)


print_r(array_chunk($i,$n,true)); //With same key postion

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 8
            [8] => 9
        )

)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I got it....Also i want to 1)add1= (1 to 3),     2)add2=(4 to 6) ,   3) add3 = (7 to 9) values

Comment: You mean you want different variables for those arrays?